# OPC UA:How can I solve the error of callmethod

Tags: python, client, call, opc-ua

I want to call the method of one node,but failed.I tried a lot but did not work.This is my code:

```
import asyncio
from asyncua import Client

url = "opc.tcp://localhost:4840"
async def main():
    print(f"Connecting to {url} ...")
    async with Client(url=url) as client:

        # Calling a method
        idname = f"ns=1;s=getCurrentAbsTime"
        var2 = client.get_node(idname)
        res = await var2.call_method("getCurrentAbsTime",[])
        print(res)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

And the error:asyncua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadNoMatch: The requested operation has no match to return.(BadNoMatch)

Please help me.
Thank you

I didn't know why the error.I had tried the inputs many times and forms but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Call a method via the parent object:

```
    idname = f"ns=1;s=?"
    obj = client.get_node(idname)
    method = await obj.get_child("1:getCurrentAbsTime")
    result = await obj.call_method(method, [])
```

Comment: I had changed my code but did not work.Also the error:asyncua.ua.uaerrors._auto.BadNoMatch: The requested operation has no match to return.(BadNoMatch)                                                                                                     
        `idname = f"ns=1;s=getCurrentAbsTime"
        obj = client.get_node(idname)
        res = await obj.call_method("1:getCurrentAbsTime",[])
        print(res)`                                                                                                         
        @Schroeder

Comment: See my edited answer